# git clone failure shows password in clear text

Tags: git, git-clone

git clone gives the below fatal error, but the problem is it exposes the password in plain text;

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://username:password@github/name/my_repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Is there any way to hide the password from git response?

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: Yes, I have the clone command as part of the script, so that i have passed username and password as part of git clone command.

Comment: The password is in the script. So it's not safe anyway. user can see it if he read the script.